# Can I have a show-like route that points to the index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

If I am using the standard show route like this:

```
GET /articles/5
```

Is it also possible to have a route like this, that points to the `index` action, and provides `'environment'` as a param, at the same time?

```
GET /articles/environment
```

Comment: To clarify: I'm guessing you want GET /articles/environment to list all articles with a tag or category of "enviornment". Is that correct?

Comment: If you're not just trying to make the URL pretty, then chances are you are trying to model the concept incorrectly.  You'll see that Rails makes things really easy when you follow the conventions, and when you don't it can become hard or hard to maintain (with answer below you are constantly going to have to check the params).  I would re-think what you are trying to model here and look for a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

yes, obviously.

The `environment` is available to you with `params[:id]` assuming that you are using RESTful resouces.